# Cannot authenticate to mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to mongodb instance (`db` container), but I get each time this error:

> MongoServerError: Authentication failed.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8088:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
```

These are the variables within `.env`:

```
DB_PORT=27017
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypwd
```

This is the connection class:

```
import * as Mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { UserModel } from './users/users.model'
import { ChatModel } from './chats/chats.model'
import { MessageModel } from './messages/messages.model'

const {
    DB_HOST,
    DB_PORT,
    DB_NAME,
    DB_USER,
    DB_PASSWORD
} = process.env

if (!DB_HOST) throw new TypeError('DB_HOST missing!')
if (!DB_PORT) throw new TypeError('DB_PORT missing!')
if (!DB_NAME) throw new TypeError('DB_NAME missing!')
if (!DB_USER) throw new TypeError('DB_USER missing!')
if (!DB_PASSWORD) throw new TypeError('DB_PASSWORD missing!')

let database: Mongoose.Connection

export const connect = (callback: Function) => {
    
    const uri = `mongodb://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?authSource=admin`

    if (database) {
        return
    }

    Mongoose.connect(uri)

    database = Mongoose.connection

    database.once('open', async () => {
        console.log('Connected to database')

        callback()
    })

    database.on('error', () => {
        console.log('Error connecting to database')
    })

    return {
        UserModel,
        ChatModel,
        MessageModel
    }
}

export const disconnect = () => {

    if (!database) {
        return
    }

    Mongoose.disconnect()
}
```

This is the list of the running containers:

[image]

The app container doesn't run 'cause there is the connection error, but the mongodb container is actually running.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Is the user really created in `admin` database? Does your password contain any special character you need to escape?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no weird character, I have a bash script that create the user when the container is created

Comment: What does that bash script look like?

Comment: @larsks I have removed the bash script, now I just use the environment variables provided by the mongo image. The weird thing is that when I exec in the container and try to login I get authentication failed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following `docker-compose.yaml` to try to reproduce your problem:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}

  client:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_client
    image: mongo
    command: sleep inf
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

I'm using the `.env` file you show in your question, with the addition of the `APP_NAME` variable:

```
DB_PORT=27017
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypwd
APP_NAME=example
```

If I bring up the stack, and then `docker exec` into the client
container and run:

```
root@4c7dd638c102:/# mongosh mongodb://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?authSource=admin
```

It seems to work just fine:

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 62a79256b9719bd467e22d03
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@db:27017/mydb?authSource=admin&directConnection=true
Using MongoDB:          5.0.0
Using Mongosh:          1.0.0
...
mydb>
```

Have you verified (e.g. by printing it out) that the `uri` variable in
your javascript code contains the value you expect?

---

If I update my reproducer to use a named volume, like this...

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - "mongo_data:/data/db"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}

  client:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_client
    image: mongo
    command: sleep inf
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

...everything continues to work just fine.

Comment: Neverming, the issue is related to: `volumes: - ./data:/data/db`, so is not possible mount the volume on the system?

Comment: Can you use a volume instead of a bind mount? Using a docker named volume instead of a bind mount will often be easier, and will avoid permissions issues that crop up when trying to access files from the container and the host.

Comment: If you had previously started mongodb with a different username or password, those would have persisted in your local `data` directory, and starting a new mongo instance with a different `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` wouldn't update the password. See if the problem persists if you `rm -rf data` before bringing things up.